# angularjs filter date, date format error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have many views, each one related to js controller using angularjs. 
I have a purchases form where there is :

```
<input type="date" ng-model="currentDate">
```

In the controller js I have :

```
$scope.currentDate=$filter('date') (new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

I used that method in all my forms and working fine but in the purchase form the date is not set as today and in the console the page gave me :

```
angular.js:12450Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-01-24
    at angular.js:38
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:21769)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:25349)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:15751)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:16030)
    at angular.js:1660
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4476)
    at d (angular.js:1658)
    at yc (angular.js:1678)
    at Xd (angular.js:1572)
```

I didn't catch where is the problem. I checked the injector ( $filter), checked the ng-model if it's duplicate, nothing. Any idea?

Comment: If you check the error link (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-01-24), it actually gives you the reason for your error: `Model is not a date object`. So `$scope.currentDate` is a string, not a date --> an error is thrown

Comment: yes I checked the link, I defined a variable containing the date, where is the problem?

Comment: Your variable is not a date, it is a string. Just do `$scope.currentDate = new Date()`

Comment: Why not something like http://plnkr.co/edit/14zJVTa0oRvNWIG4lHOv?p=preview

Comment: Fissio, working, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All date-related inputs like  require the model to
>   be a Date object. If the model is something else, this error will be
>   thrown

This is explanation found in the error url provided.

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date();
```

This should work for you. You were providing the formatted date string as input, which is not expected.